# Using pecl to install the Mongodb driver on OS X El Capitan (v10.11.1)

Tags: php, xcode, macos, mongodb, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to install the php mongo driver for OS X. I've tried following [these instructions](http://jafdip.com/how-to-install-mongodb-and-the-php-mongo-drive-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-server/) to no avail.

`$ which pecl` -> `/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.13_2/bin/pecl`

`$ sudo pecl install mongo` -> full build results [here](https://goo.gl/XvQJl0) but the problem the is the error:

```
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/io_stream.c:34:
/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/contrib/php-ssl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'openssl/evp.h' file not found
#include <openssl/evp.h>
```

My Xcode command-line tools are up to date (I used `$ xcode-select --install` to be sure).

I'm sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: Why down-vote my question? I've researched the issue and can't find a solution for El Capitan.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I managed to get around this by installing OpenSSL using Homebrew ([as suggested here](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1630#issuecomment-147527656)):

```
$ brew install openssl
$ brew link openssl --force
```

Then

```
$ sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Comment: Notably `mongo` is the deprecated package name; people should be using `mongodb`. The forced brew linking works also with the newer package `mongodb`. Thanks!

Comment: @EzekielVictor Saved my day!

Comment: Sure thing... I submitted an edit now to update his answer. Probably should have done that to begin with.

Comment: This won't work anymore and should be unsafe.

Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

Comment: @EzekielVictor I updated to mac os Sierra and when I try execute brew install open ssl it says "Warning: openssl-1.0.2j already installed", and again when I execute brew link openssl --force it says "Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" 

Any idea how to get it work?

Answer (score 9):

Do this

```
$ cd /usr/local/include 
$ ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl
```

Comment: I already had openssl and pkg-config and still was getting the error. This solution worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well, after exhausting all the other solutions available online.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using http://phpbrew.github.io/phpbrew/ for this type of thing. It let's you easily install any extensions to any php version you require.

When installing a new version of php, I usually keep an eye on the log while it compiles. There might be dependencies that need installing first. Also, make sure you have an updated version of homebrew installed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to disable the Mac OSX El Capitán rootless mechanism:

1. Boot with Cmd-R
2. Open Terminal
3. Type csrutil disable
4. Reboot

On the Mac, You need to install Xcode, and build the symlink for the openssl comes with Xcode, i.e.

```
cd /usr/include;
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-migrator/sdk/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/openssl
```