# Mongo DB PHP Driver Installation Fails on OS X Sierra

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, homebrew

I just updated to Mac OS Sierra version 10.12.1 and executed

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Installation failed and shows this message

```
Configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/configure' failed
```

Also tried using Homebrew installation

```
brew install php56-mongo
```

but still mongo db php driver is not installed phpinfo() doesn't show the mongo extension.

Also tried with the solution provided here [Using pecl to install the Mongodb driver on OS X El Capitan (v10.11.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483210/using-pecl-to-install-the-mongodb-driver-on-os-x-el-capitan-v10-11-1)

when I try execute

```
brew install openssl 

Warning: openssl-1.0.2j already installed
```

and again when I execute 
`brew link openssl --force` it says

```
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

Any idea how to get it work?

Comment: Also see [Brew refusing to link openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You must first tap the PHP formula repository from terminal like so

```
brew tap homebrew/php
```

in order to install PHP extensions like MongoDB via Homebrew.
After tapping the formula repository, install the MongoDB extension

```
brew install php56-mongo
```

In my case I had php56-mongo driver installed

After installation check the location of where mongo.so is located in file

```
/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-mongo.ini
```

Just Copy the location of mongo.so path

```
extension="/usr/local/opt/php56-mongo/mongo.so"
```

Add in php.ini and restart apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Now Finally check the phpinfo() and it should show the mongo driver installed

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install the "pkg-config" package as well. The PHP driver for MongoDB uses that to find out about OpenSSL.

Comment: I already have pkg-config installed, pkg-config --version gives 0.29.1